# Error Android OnClickfindViewById

Tags: android, android-imageview, onclick

Buenas tengo que crear una animación con una imagen y a la hora de crear el método `onClick()` me da error en `findViewById()`. Si alguien me pudiese ayudar estaría agradecido

El error no se cual es ya que llamo a la `imageView` imagen correctamente, necesito ayuda

He seguido los pasos correctamente y aun así me da error: Para que la animación se visualice, hay que cargarla, asociarla a la imagen y
ponerla en marcha. Vaya al método `onClick()` que ha escrito antes y añada lo
siguiente:

```
    public class Pelota extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
        public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    
        private int mPage;
    
        public static Pelota newInstance() {
            Pelota fragment = new Pelota();
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    
    
    
    
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pelota, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            return view;
        }
    
        public void onClick (View view){
    
            ImageView imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
            Animation animacionPelota = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.botar);
            imagen.startAnimation(animacionPelota);
    
        }
    
    
    
    }

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Aqui añado pelota.xml para saber el error exactamente ya que llamo a la imageView correctamente:
```

En el XML le paso un textview y la imageview a la cual le paso la animacion y donde me declaro el id a imagen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="353dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/basketball" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Carlos, agrega pelota.xml  a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el elemento con id  `pelota` no es un `ImageView` por lo tanto no puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
ImageView imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pelota);
```

de hecho `pelota` en realidad es un layout ya que es la vista que inflas al inicio dentro de `onCreateView()`:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pelota, container, false);
```

dentro de `pelota.xml` el id del `ImageView`  es `imagen`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_width="384dp"
    android:layout_height="353dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/basketball" />
```

Por lo tanto obten de esta manera su referencia:

```
ImageView imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
```

---

Actualización:

Al obtener el error:

> error: cannot find symbol imagen = (ImageView)
> findViewById(R.id.imagen); ^ symbol: method findViewById(int)
> location: class Pelota

Se debe a que necesitas el contexto para llamar el método `findViewById()` , en este caso te propongo obtener la referencia del `ImageView` dentro de `onCreateView()` y dentro del método `onClick()` configuras la animación del ImageView:

```
public class Pelota extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    private ImageView imagen;

    public static Pelota newInstance() {
        Pelota fragment = new Pelota();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pelota, container, false);
        //Obtiene referencia de ImageView.
        imagen = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        return view;
    }

    public void onClick (View view){
        //Configura animación.      
        Animation animacionPelota = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.botar);
        imagen.startAnimation(animacionPelota);

    }



}
```

Comment: Buenas si llamo al id de la imageView que lo he cambiado ahora a imagen y sigue dandome error, mira mi pelota.xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="353dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/basketball" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: ok agrega el .xml @Carlos

Comment: ya esta agregado

Comment: Gracias @Carlos de hecho debes usar  ImageView imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen); si tienes un error seguramente es otro diferente, especifica que mensaje de error se muestra.

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
        imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
                             ^
  symbol:   method findViewById(int)
  location: class Pelota

Comment: Lo que quiero realizar es que cuando pulse sobre la pelota realize una animación

Comment: El error se debe a que necesitas el contexto para llamar el método findViewById() , revisa la actualización @Carlos

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con pasar el contexto? ¿Se lo paso al metodo onClick()?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117354/discussion-between-elenasys-and-carlos).